# Sending message using Telegram api

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-curl, php-telegram-bot

I have some `PHP` code to sending message to `Telegram_bot`:

```
$telegrambot = "xxxxxxx"; 
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$telegrambot; 
$chatId=yyyyyyy; 
$params=array('chat_id'=>$chatId,'text'=>$msg,);    

$ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

I used `curl` because using `file_get_contents()` or `fopen()` causes `connection refused` error. But still it doesn't work. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of Bot Code Examples available for PHP Telegram API integration.

Please check it.

**Bot Code Examples:** https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples

- PHP Telegram API. A complete PHP7 Bot API implementation for
  Telegram. https://github.com/unreal4u/telegram-api
- PHP Telegram Bot. A pure PHP Telegram Bot, fully extensible via
  plugins. https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot
- Bot API PHP SDK. An SDK with Laravel support.
  https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple hello bot which is written in PHP.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples/hellobot